# How to hook it all together (resolve, service, controller, $scope)

Tags: angularjs

I have a template in which I need an editingTimesheet and a list of allowed_times (this one is calculated based on the date of the editingTimesheet).

I found out that the code of the controller only seems to run once and not when I do a $state.go(

Watching the egghead video's I saw that resolve (in the state) is being used to force data to be loaded before opening the form.  With the code I have now, the $scope.timesheet is being set before the editingTimesheet becomes loaded (same with the allowed_times).  How can I fix this?

In my service I have this code:

```
.factory('Timesheets', function($resource, $rootScope, LinkData, Company) {
  var Timesheet = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/timesheets/:id',{id:'@id'}, {update:{method:'PUT'}});
  var _allowed_times;

  return {
    timesheet: function() {
      return Timesheet;
    },
    allowed_times: function() {
      return this._allowed_times
    },
    get: function(id){
      return Timesheet.query({q: {id_eq: id}}).$promise.then(function (data, status) {
        this.editingTimesheet = data;
        Company.allowed_times(data.currentDate).then(function(data2) { //fill allowed times
          this._allowed_times = data2;
        });
      });
    }
  }
})
```

In the controller I have this:

```
var TimesheetDetailCtrl = app.controller('TimesheetDetailCtrl', function($scope, Timesheets) {
  $scope.allowed_times = Timesheets.allowed_times();
  $scope.timesheet = Timesheets.editingTimesheet;
}
```

I have also got this function that I map to resolve in the .state:

```
TimesheetDetailCtrl.beforeShow = function($q, $stateParams, Timesheets) {
  Timesheets.get($stateParams.timesheetId);
};
```

And finally I have this state:

```
.state('timesheet-detail', {
  url: '/timesheet/:timesheetId',
  templateUrl: 'templates/timesheet-detail.html',
  controller: 'TimesheetDetailCtrl',
    resolve: {
      reset: TimesheetDetailCtrl.beforeShow
    }
})
```

**Extra question:** the beforeShow function will be executed each time that template is loaded.  The code in the controller not:

```
  $scope.timesheet = Timesheets.editingTimesheet;
```

Am I correct assuming that when the Timesheets.editingTimesheet changes, it will automatically also change the $scope.timesheet and that's why the code in the controller won't need to run every time?

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of problems here.

1. You cannot pass `$rootScope` to factory like that. You can pass `$rootScope` or '$scope' to factory method from controller or so. Factories are singletons. e.g. `Timesheets.allowed_times($scope)`
2. Resolve definition does not appear to be appropriate.

*The resolve option takes an object where the keys are the names of the dependencies to inject into
the controller and the values are the factories that are to be resolved.*
So, resolve is evaluated before controller gets initialized.

I guess you need to do following changes to your code

```
.state('timesheet-detail', {
  url: '/timesheet/:timesheetId',
  templateUrl: 'templates/timesheet-detail.html',
  controller: 'TimesheetDetailCtrl',
    resolve: {
      reset: ['$stateParams', 'Timesheets', function($stateParams, Timesheets){
        Timesheets.get($stateParams.timesheetId);
      };
    }
})
```

You may not require TimesheetDetailCtrl.beforeShow method here.

**OR**

You can just modify your controller constructor as given below and remove `resolve`

```
var TimesheetDetailCtrl = app.controller('TimesheetDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Timesheets',  function($scope, $stateParams, Timesheets) {
  Timesheets.get($stateParams.timesheetId);
  $scope.allowed_times = Timesheets.allowed_times();
  $scope.timesheet = Timesheets.editingTimesheet;
])};
```

**Regarding extra questions...**
I believe, controller constructor runs on each template load.

```
$scope.timesheet = Timesheets.editingTimesheet;
```

when the Timesheets.editingTimesheet changes, $scope.timesheet will not change in your case as your always getting new 'data' object.
If you keep the reference intact, then only it works.

You need to change editingTimesheet to an object containing data.
e.g.

```
Timesheets.editingTimesheet = {tsInstance: data}
$scope.timesheet = Timesheets.editingTimesheet;
in html, access with 
{{timesheet.tsInstance}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.  I'm using Ionic beta 14 and they enabled cached views.

See here for details: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Relevant part:
Note that because we are caching these views, we aren’t destroying scopes. Instead, scopes are being disconnected from the watch cycle. Because scopes are not being destroyed and recreated, **controllers are not loading again on a subsequent viewing**.

After disabling the caching in the state provider everything worked as expected:

Disable cache within state provider

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
  cache: false,
  url : '/myUrl',
  templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})
```